# Disabled always use location for Google Maps, but I still get "Google Maps is using your location"

Tags: ios, privacy, google

So basically, here are my settings for Google Maps for iOS (running on an iPhone):

[image]

As can be seen Location is set to **While Using**, and Background App Refresh is **turned off**.

But, still when I exit from Google Maps, I get the message that it is actively using my location:

[image]

I remember few iOS update ago this didn't happen. I have an iPhone 6s running iOS 12.2.

How do I disable Google Maps from accessing the location after leave the app by pressing the Home button?

Comment: Does the status bar shows this momentarily when you press the Home button? Is the app working in navigation mode?

Comment: I've seen this from time to time, I find that a double-tap on the home button and then swipe that app up, seems to kill that.

Comment: @NimeshNeema: yes the app is in navigation mode, it appears when I press Home while navigating

Comment: @Steve: yes if I kill the app the message on top disappears, but the fact is that it shouldn't appear when I go home

Comment: to downvoter: care to explain ? I think the question is fair

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps uses one of the special privilege modes in iOS called [background execution mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). Background execution is crucial for certain kind of apps such as those playing music, VoIP apps and the ones which provide navigation functionality.

Apps with the said requirements can be programmed in a special way so that they can continue execution even after you return back to the Home screen. Since the Google Maps app is providing navigation functionality (which can include spoken navigation), it continues to run when you press the Home button. Since the app is using location, the same is shown to you in the form of elongated and highlighted status bar.

Comment: ok good, but i disabled all the background stuff in the app settings

Comment: @giò Background execution mode is different from Background App Refresh settings. While the later gives your app the ability to run "momentarily" at opportune moments, the former lets your app "run uninterrupted". Uninterrupted execution is required is special cases such as VoIP call, audio playback and navigation. The Google Maps app is continuously running in the background mode.

Comment: then i don't understand how i can disable that

Comment: @giò The point is that you can't. How do you expect Google Maps to provide navigation if the app itself isn't running. To turn off position (location) access, you'll need to quit the Google Maps app, which in turn will stop navigation.

Comment: google maps should provide navigation as long as is the active app on the screen... if i go home it shouldn't provide navigation if i have disabled all the background stuff... this sounds reasonable to me

Comment: @giò Navigation mode doesn't dictate that you look at the screen "all-the-time". It is by design  that navigation in mobile apps is capable of running in background and there's no way to turn it off.

Comment: ok thank you for the explanation, althou I think it's not intuitite like this, because it goes againt the background settings of the app.. but you know it's Apple, and not always is intuitive :D

Comment: @giò You are welcome. The concept has nothing to do with "Apple is Apple". The concept applies equally well to Android and well for any other mobile platform.